# ACRCloud Unity SDK Offline Recognition

Tags: unity-game-engine, offline, acrcloud

I've downloaded the Unity3D ACRCloud SDK from github and works very good, now I'm trying to make it work the offline recognition, I've followed the documentation and created an offline DB, added to the assets but looks like I can't configure neither the recMode as local neither the local path to the db.

Anybody knows a fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unity3D ACRCloud SDK does not support offline recognition. Please try Android or iOS SDK for offline recognition.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Just tried the iOS SDK and it works pretty good.
It's possible to enhance the unity SDK with the iOS one?

Comment: Sorry, we don't have a plan to do that. If you have custom request, please send emails to support@acrcloud.com Thanks